# delivery performance

Tags: problem-solving

I need to calculate average speed of a driver as a performance indicator.
I have the total miles driven and the total hours they took. Simple 
division of mi/hr is the speed. But I want to factor in the number of stops
they're going. How can I incorporate number of stops so that the speed
will be a more accurate measure of performance indicator? More stops 
would probably mean less speed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the time the stops take and add it to the time it took to get wherever the driver was going. Then, as you said, divide by the time, and you'll get the average speed (which, as you mentioned, will be less than the speed the car is going when it IS going and not stopped).

Comment: the time I have already has those stop times in it. I guess I want to really include the number of stops somehow. Maybe what I'm looking for may not be the speed. I want to measure performance.

Comment: @Mike, remember 2 stops of 10 minutes is the same as 5 stops of 4 minutes in matters for speed efficiency. How would you like to include the number of stops? What really matters about stops is their number times their length.